# Error with react native bottom tab navigator

Tags: react-native

Here is the full error:  ERROR  Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found ' '). To render this component in the navigator, pass it in the 'component' prop to 'Screen'.

This error is located at:
in StackNavigator (created by StackNavigator)
in StackNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)

app.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import RegisterScreen from './screens/register';
import LoginScreen from './screens/login';
import SearchScreen from './screens/search';
import DeleteScreen from './screens/delete'; // Import the DeleteScreen component
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { firebaseConfig } from './config';
import MainTabNavigator from './navigation/tabNavigator';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  firebase.app();
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName={'Dashboard'}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={MainTabNavigator} /> 
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};


export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StackNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

tabNavigator.js

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import SearchScreen from '../screens/search';
import DeleteScreen from '../screens/delete';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default class MainTabNavigator extends React.Component {
    render() 
  {return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Delete" component={DeleteScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );}
};
```

Comment: Have you tried change `MainTabNavigator` to `Function Component`?

Comment: It used to be a functional component, but then I turned it into a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have done the above scenario:

```
/* MainStackNavigator.js */

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

const TabNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="TAB1" component={TabOne}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="TAB2" component={TabTwo}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

const MainStackNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Splash'>
                <Stack.Screen name='Splash' component={SplashScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={LoginScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name='Tab' component={TabNavigator} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

Try this way keeping both navigators in a common file, and then use it in App.js like this:

```
/* App.js */

import MainStackNavigator from './src/navigation/MainStackNavigator';

const App = () => {
  return (
        <View style={appStyles.fullFlex}>
          <MainStackNavigator />
          <Toast />
        </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote the function in app.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import RegisterScreen from './screens/register';
import LoginScreen from './screens/login';
import SearchScreen from './screens/search';
import DeleteScreen from './screens/delete'; // Import the DeleteScreen component
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { firebaseConfig } from './config';
import MainTabNavigator from './navigation/tabNavigator';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
 firebase.app();
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


const StackNavigator = () => {
 return (
   <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName={'Dashboard'}>
     <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
     <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
     <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={tabNavigator} /> 
   </Stack.Navigator>
 );
};
const tabNavigator = () =>{
 return(
   <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
   <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
   <Tab.Screen name="Delete" component={DeleteScreen} />
 </Tab.Navigator>
 )
}


export default function App() {
 return (
   <NavigationContainer>
     <StackNavigator />
   </NavigationContainer>
 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**